# How to delete line_items from a woocommerce order using python

Tags: python, django, woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api

I am trying unsuccessfully to delete all the products related with a woocommerce order in order to update this order with new products.

To do this I guess the 1st step is to delete all the *line_items* of the specific order and make a put to update.

The 2nd step is again to make a put but with the new products this time in the position of line_items.

**Has anyone any idea what's going wrong with my code?**

In this post , https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/issues/22177, I saw that I have to put in the quantity field of every product in my *line_items* the value of 0, but it doesn't work.

Here is my code:

```
def update_woocommerce_order_products_with_quantities(wcapi,order,oldWooOrderHasProducts):


    fetched_products=Woo_Order_Has_Products.objects.filter(woo_order_id=order_id)

    #FIRST I HAVE TO DELETE THE PRODUCTS OF THE WOOCOMMERCE ORDER
    for oldWooOrderHasProduct in oldWooOrderHasProducts:
        data = {
            "line_items": [
        {
            "id": str(oldWooOrderHasProduct.wholesale_product.pid),
            "quantity": 0,
        }
        ]
            }

    wcapi.put("orders/"+str(oid),data).json()


    #for every product update the price and quantity
    for fetched_product in fetched_products:

        data = {
            "line_items": [
        {
            "id": str(fetched_product.wholesale_product.pid),
            "quantity": str(fetched_product.quantity),
            "price": str(fetched_product.price)
        }]
            }

    wcapi.put("orders/"+str(oid),data).json()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to delete the existing products in line_items for an order you have to:

1) fetch from the woocommerce rest api the line_items. The oid is the order's id.

```
r=wcapi.get("orders/"+str(oid)).json()
line_items=r['line_items']
```

2) create the data dictionary based on the `line_items` key. The important thing is putting the quantity of every product in `line_items` equals to zero.

```
data = {"line_items": []}
for line_item in line_items:
data["line_items"].append({
"id": line_item["id"],
"quantity": 0
})
```

3) Update the data through the woocommerce rest api.

```
wcapi.put("orders/"+str(oid),data).json()
```

Answer (score 1):

Here:

```
for oldWooOrderHasProduct in oldWooOrderHasProducts:
    data = {
        "line_items": [
    {
        "id": str(oldWooOrderHasProduct.wholesale_product.pid),
        "quantity": 0,
    }
    ]
        }

wcapi.put("orders/"+str(oid),data).json()
```

You are rebinding `data` on each iteration, so only the last value is used for the API call. You want to create the `data` dict outside the loop and only append to `line_items` within the loop:

```
data = {"line_items": []}

for oldWooOrderHasProduct in oldWooOrderHasProducts:
    data["line_items"].append({
        "id": str(oldWooOrderHasProduct.wholesale_product.pid),
        "quantity": 0,
        })
```

And you have the same issue for the second loop.